# Double slash in URL with navigation-rules JSF 2.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, migration

Hi I have problem with navigation rule in JSF 2.1. This configuration was working with JSF 1.2. In the project is used few extra libraries: JSF 2.1, RichFaces 4.2, Tomahawk, Spring 3.1, urlrewrite, acegi.

The problem is:

I am opening page in a browser URL: localhost:8080/cat1/cat2, I see index.xhtml page. I am filling the form and clicking the button, after a 2 seconds i can see result on page.xhtml, everything is ok, but the URL in a browser have double slash. There is  localhost:8080/cat1/cat2//index.xhtml instead of localhost:8080/cat1/cat2/page.xhtml .

When i am trying to click on some link on my page.xhtml I see page no found because of double slash in URL.

On the page.xhtml i have button calculate again, which invoke the same method form bean. After click on this button response is ok, my URL is localhost:8080/cat1/cat2/page.xhtml without double slash. All links on page work.

When i type the URL: localhost:8080/cat1/cat2/index.xhtml, and will click on the button i can see my page.xhtml but the URL is localhost:8080/cat1/cat2/ and all links on page works

I added this line:

```
<from-action>#{bean.method}</from-action>
```

but didn't help

button on  my index.html:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.method}" value="" styleClass="method right" tabindex="8" />
```

action:

```
public String method() {    
    // few instruction
    return "success";
}
```

Rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/cat1/cat2/*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/cat1/cat2/page.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <!-- Here is more cases -->
</navigation-rule>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double **`//`** is because of the starting **`/`** in your welcome file, it should be `index.xhtml` and not `/index.xhtml`.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In JSF 2.0 you do not have to explicitly write navigation rules in the faces-config.xml. You can just return the outcome view id.

So if you return "success" in your action method, then it will fetch `success.xhtml` automatically.

So just return "page" and you can remove the navigation rule from your `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: @k.nieszporek Just as an additional comment, implicit navigation (returning the outcome view id to let JSF redirect you yo that page) only works with pages located in the same folder. In other cases you'll have to use good old navigation rules. Check [this link](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/09/learning-jsf2-navigation/) for a nice explanation on how does navigation in JSF2 work.

Comment: @Gamb, you can return the full path if the page resides in another folder. Even conditional navigation as written in the link you posted can also be done in the same action method with if-then-else , you do not have to write navigation rules for that also.

Comment: @Ravi The redaction of my previous comment was wrong, I wanted to say that the way you gave as an example only works with pages in the same folder. Still, having absolute paths accross pages/beans over the entire application makes maintenance a headache unless you use some kind of structure to map your own rules... which in the end is unnecesary since you can define navigation rules directly.It's a matter of considering pros & cons.